# Git on Windows problems

Tags: windows, git, ssh, cmd

I am running Git on my Windows 8 vm.  I have Git bash working no problem with bitbucket.  However, I just want to use Command Prompt.  I can run git commands from Command Prompt but for some reason it feels like the ssh keys are out of sync, almost if the command prompt is trying to use something other than what bash is using.  The error I get when trying to do a simple git pull from command prompt is

`Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

I don't have any issues running the command from git bash.  What is even more maddening is that this was working a couple weeks ago. I don't recall doing anything that would have changed this.  Maybe a reboot at most.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its possible that the home directory is set differently between Git Bash and Command Prompt.  Compare the outputs of the following on both Command Prompt and Git Bash.

```
ssh -v -T git@github.com
```

you may need to change your home directory.